# Mouse won't work but its light is on

Tags: windows-10, usb, drivers, mouse, usb-3

It all happened after I plugged in my new Kingston DataTraveler Mini 3.0 memory stick into my USB 3.0 port (I have 2xUSB 3.0 and 2xUSB 2.0). The mouse stopped working, I tried plugging it into the USB 3.0 port and it worked for a few seconds, then it stopped again. All this happened in Ubuntu 16.04 but I tried it in Windows 10 and the same thing happened. Actually when I booted in Window's Safe Mode it worked again for a few seconds in one of the USB 3.0 ports before dying again. I think it has to do with the drivers but when I go on the Device Manager I can only see this:

[image: Device Manager]

So I don't know how to manage the mouse's drivers. I am on a laptop by the way, an Asus K501U if that matters. The mouse is a quite old but decent Kraun KR.MG.

Any idea?
Thank you

EDIT:
I turned off the 'Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power option' option of the 'USB Root Hub' in Device Manager > Universal Serial Buse controllers and now it works but it keeps disconnecting and reconnecting so every few seconds the pointer will stop and then move again. How do I fix this?

Comment: Add your comment as an edit to your question. Then delete your comment. The comment is really part of the question (clarification), and should be included as such. You can classify it as an edit if you wish.

Comment: And if you unplug your USB 3.0 pen drive (don't use it), does the mouse work?

Comment: I tried with and without the pen drive, it doesn't make any difference.